# Homebrew error installing tomcat

Tags: homebrew

After installing tomcat on Os x El Capitan using Homebrew I have received the following Warning:

> your HOMEBREW_PREFIX is set to /usr/local but HOMEBREW_CELLAR is set
>   to /usr/local/Cellar. Your current HOMEBREW_CELLAR location will stop
>   you being able to use all the binary packages (bottles) Homebrew
>   provides. We recommend you move your HOMEBREW_CELLAR to
>   /usr/local/Cellar which will get you access to all bottles."

The `command brew services list` shows no services installed.
Printenv doesn't show any homebrew variable
It's not clear to me what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have received a similar warning when I tried to do a brew update. 
It did not allow me to update. All I have done to resolve it was do a brew update in going to the /usr/local/Cellar directory.
From what I understand HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY path was modified or went missing when the OS was updated. After the brew update, the message said 
Migrated HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY to /usr/local/Homebrew!
**Homebrew no longer needs to have ownership of /usr/local. If you wish you can
return /usr/local to its default ownership with:
  sudo chown root:wheel /usr/local**

This got me back to my normal brew usage with out a problem.

Comment: I got: chown: /usr/local: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 10):

[enter link description here](http://discourse.brew.sh/t/warning-your-homebrew-prefix-is-set-to-usr-local-but-homebrew-cellar-is-set-to-usr-local-cellar-your-current-homebrew-cellar/229)

I also encountered this problem, in the end of the page to get accurate help,

```
brew bundle dump

rm -rf /usr/local/Homebrew/Cellar

brew bundle
```

Comment: This works for me! Thank's